# Mongo MMS monitoring service stuck operations

Tags: mongodb-mms

I have a new MMS Mongo account which I want to use for monitoring a test deployment. I tried to add an existing deployment with a replica set, but the service was just adding a new one and started to make unwanted changes to my cluster.

I shut down all automation agents on the hosts, and now in the MMS deployment view, the operations show as pending since yesterday. Is there a way I can cancel them?

Currently no agents of any kind are running on any host.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At this time the new MMS does not support importation of existing MongoDB processes. We are working on this, but I'm afraid I can't give you an ETA at this time.

To get rid of the pending operations, go to your "Deployment" page, go into "edit mode" and then select your replica set for editing. This should make a black sidebar appear on the right side of the window. Then click the gear at the top of this and select "unmanage". This should get rid of the pending operations once you commit those changes.

Regards,

-Peter

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried what you suggested but the options are grayed out. The operations are in a pending state for almost a week now.

Comment: My apologies, I had the wrong link there. You need to click the "Edit Deployment" link, then confirm on the dialog box that pops up, and then you can make changes.